# Split string with different delimiters (characters) in Python

Tags: python, regex, split, regex-split

I have a string like below.

```
s = 'Frozen Meals_NA_ Delicious_Market-Sponsored-Retail|Best Deals | MN |Fabulous'
```

I'd like to split it into a list like below.

```
['Frozen', 'Meals', 'NA', 'Delicious', 'Market', 'Sponsored', 'Retail', 'Best', 'Deals', 'MN', 'Fabulous']
```

I tried using `re.split()` like below.

```
re.split(r'[\s,.|\_-]+',s,re.I)
# returns ['Frozen', 'Meals', 'NUSA_SSS_NA_ Ecommerce_Amazon-SP-Brands|Sponsored | GAA |Nespresso']
```

I tried below as well.

```
>>> re.split(r'\W+',s,re.I)
# returns ['Frozen', 'Meals_NUSA_SSS_NA_', 'Ecommerce_Amazon-SP-Brands|Sponsored | GAA |Nespresso']
```

Is there a way to split string with several different delimiters in Python and extract just one word entities from the original string?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: `re.I` should be `flags=re.I`. You're assigning that value to the `limit` argument, not `flags`.

Comment: Yes, you can also omit `re.I` as you are not matching lower or uppercase chars `re.split(r'[\s,.|_-]+', s)`

Comment: @Barmar and The fourth bird Thank you very much for highlighting my mistake! I somehow thought the third parameter to `re.split()` function is the flag. Now it is working as expected. :)

Comment: It's a common mistake, since other `re` functions take the flags as the next argument.